# My login with google button takes to homepage first and then shows the sign in options(email accounts). What to do here?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am developing my project in the flutter. I am trying to make a login page in flutter using google sign in authentication using firebase. I have built it, but when I click on login with Google button it first takes to the homepage and then it shows sign-In options, but it should have been vice versa. Help me out here.

Here is the login Page [Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26VUH.png).

This shows after I click on 'Login with Google' button [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwfTu.png).

And Now Finally sign-in option appears [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8i9.png).

This is My Code

Google Sign in authentication

```
//google sign in
 final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn=  GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async{
    //GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("User Name: ${user.displayName}");
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    return user;
  }
```

Login Button

```
RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login with Google'),
                color: Colors.orange,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 7.0,
                onPressed: () { _signIn();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                }
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why return the user in `_signIn()` if you do nothing with it?

Instead, I'd move the navigation statement at the end of `_signIn()`, because `_signIn()` is `async`:

```dart
//google sign in
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn=  GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async{
    //GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("User Name: ${user.displayName}");
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
  }
```

```dart
RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login with Google'),
                color: Colors.orange,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 7.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  _signIn(); 
                }
              ),
```

Comment: what if I have created another file to do the authentication part and in there I can not do Navigator.of(context).....below asser(user.id==currentUser.uid); then what would I do? Because If i write navigator....it says context is not defined

Answer (score 0):

another possibility would be:

```
RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Login with Google'),
            color: Colors.orange,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 7.0,
            onPressed: () {
              _signIn().then(() 
               {Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage')}); 
            }
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are navigating to home screen on button press as -

```
RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Login with Google'),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    onPressed: () { _signIn();
                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                    }
                  ),
```

It should be as below-

```
RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Login with Google'),
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    onPressed: () { _signIn();

                    }
                  ),
```

After get proper response from google login you can navigate to home screen by adding "Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');"

Comment: Please go through - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166076/5523949
There is complete code of where to write navigator code. and if you are using another class then at the time of calling you can pass context in that class.